# Packaging tomcat into RPM for web deployment

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, web-deployment, rpm

I need to build RPM file which does tomcat installation and places the war file into webapps location and starts the server.
How do i package tomcat into RPM? How do i tell to place WAR file into webapps after installation?

Comment: do you want to build a complete bundle of tomcat and your application code that will deploy it automatically and start it?

Comment: I just want to package war file not the entire application code. SO my rpm package should have tomcat and war file in it. So that when rpm is installed tomcat should get installed and war file should be placed in webapps folder of installed tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat installation survives if Java is available on the server. So, better it is to have your war file in webapps directory and then compress (tar) your tomcat directory into a single file as (this also wants java):

```
tar -czf tomcat.tar.tgz <path of your tomcat directory>
```

On the server where you want to install tomcat, just copy this file (tomcat.tar.tgz) and decompress this on the desired location as:

```
tar -xzf tomcat.tar.tgz
```